# Beginner - Deep comparaison in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Disclaimer : I'm a total beginner in JS

Well I'm reading Eloquent Javascript and one of the exercices is deep comparaison of objects in JS.

There are objects defined like :

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
```

and you're supposed to check if their contents are equal.
Then there are 3 tests :

```
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj)); // supposed to return true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2})); // supposed to return false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2})); // supposed to return true
```

Here is my implementation of the deep equal method. To simplify I assumed the objects compared have the same structure, which they wont in real life but then my method should return false (I think)

```
function deepEqual(obj1,obj2)
{
console.log("========");
  for(prop in obj1)
  {
    console.log(prop);
    if (typeof(prop)=="object" && prop!=null)
    {
        console.log("Inspecting object ", obj1[prop],obj2[prop]);
        if (!deepEqual(obj1[prop],obj2[prop]))
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Inspecting property ",prop,'[',obj1[prop],'][',obj2[prop],']');
      if (obj1[prop]!=obj2[prop])
      { 
        console.log("Different property");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

It returns respectively true, false and ....false !

Here is the output:

```
========
here
Inspecting property  here [ {is: "an"} ][ {is: "an"} ]
object
Inspecting property  object [ 2 ][ 2 ]
true
========
here
Inspecting property  here [ {is: "an"} ][ 1 ]
Different property
false
========
here
Inspecting property  here [ {is: "an"} ][ {is: "an"} ]
Different property
false
```

There are two things I don't understand :

- Why does it always go to "Inspecting property" and never to "Inspecting object" ? {is: "an"} is an object isn't it ?
- Why is the expression "obj1[prop]!=obj2[prop]" true, although, according to the logs, they are both equal to : {is: "an"} ?

FYI, the reference implementation from the book is :

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}
```

To me the first for loop just counts how many properties there are in A right ?
I'm totally confused by the second for loop ( for (var prop in b) ) though ...

EDIT : Thanks a lot for the answers guys ! I don't know which one to accept as both helped me a lot :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prop` (in your `for (prop in obj)` loop) is not a value - it's a key ([`for in` loop on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). When using `for in` loops, you reference values like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
}
```

---

As for the second question:

> Why is the expression "obj1[prop]!=obj2[prop]" true, although,
>   according to the logs, they are both equal to : {is: "an"} ?

Please note that when comparing two objects (or any other non-primitive value), they are compared **by reference**, not by value:

```
var obj1 = { name: true };
var obj2 = { name: true };
obj1 === obj2;
-> false (obj1 and obj2 are different objects)

var obj3 = { name: true };
var obj4 = obj3;
obj3 === obj4;
-> true (obj4 is basically a reference to obj3)
```

---

**Side note**: a good practice in JavaScrpt is to use `===` (strict comparison) operator instead of `==` (abstract comparison). Why? Because the former one does not implicitly convert compared values to other types. Javascript's type conversion is not so obvious, so it's better to stick with more predictable operator. Using strict comparison is generally more safe way to compare things in JS.

You can read more about the topic [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: I thought === meant by reference and == by value ? So how do you compare by value ?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. You can read my **Side note** or go straight to the documentation on [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: As for the ``by value`` comparison - that's what your ``deepEqual`` function is basically for (when comparing non-primitive values). Primitive values (like Strings or Numbers) are **always** compared by value - the difference between ``==`` and ``===`` is type conversion (explained in my **Side note**).

Comment: Alright, so in the case of objects, === returns true if both operands refer to the same object BUT in the case of primitive types (like strings), the content is compared. Ok got it. Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
if (typeof(prop)=="object" && prop!=null)
```

`prop` is the key of the property, which is always a string, not the value of the property. It should be:

```
if (typeof(obj1[prop])=="object" && obj1[prop]!=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a great analogy that might help with this question:

> Why is the expression "obj1[prop]!=obj2[prop]" true, although,
>   according to the logs, they are both equal to : {is: "an"} ?

Me and my brother can say we have the SAME mother.

Me and that guy over there can say we have the SAME car because we both have a black Toyota Camry.

```
My Mother === My Brother's Mother  // true, she is really the same person.

My car === Guy's car               // false, looks the same but 2 different cars
```

```
obj !== {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2} // just looks the same
```

=== is strict equality such as `"3" === 3 // false` ... AND ...
== ignores datatype such as `"3" == 3 // true`